# I want to find a hash function to generate a hash with a given length

Tags: function, hash

Just like the title, I want to find a hash function to generate a hash with a given length. From the Internet I found one solution is I can use the SHAKE256 technique. But I cannot find some java code to use the SHAKE256. Anyone can provide me some sample java code so that I can use it in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed `java shake256` into Google and found this solution as the 2nd result: https://github.com/aelstad/keccakj. It is a Java library called "keccakj" that is able to compute shake256 hashes, among others.

Comment: I also found that resource, but inside it I did not find any method which take the outout length as a argument, can you please check it?

Comment: Looks like there is an example in the readme that includes a variable called `whatever_size_you_like`. Sounds like that should be what you're looking for? https://github.com/aelstad/keccakj#messagedigests-1

Answer (score 0):

For shake256, to generate a hash of an arbitrary bit length `d` and `d` < 256, you can just trim the result of `SHAKEDigest` from [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org).

```
    public static byte[] hash(byte[] src, int byteLength){
        //import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHAKEDigest;
        Assert.assertTrue("do not support result length more than 32", byteLength<=32);
        SHAKEDigest d = new SHAKEDigest(256);
        byte[]checksumByte = new byte[32];
        d.update(src,0,src.length);
        d.doFinal(checksumByte,0);
        return Arrays.copyOf(checksumByte,byteLength);
    }
```